# POST data not posting

Tags: php, post

So I am making a register script and have this form code:

```
    <form action="do_register.php" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" id="username"/><br />
        Password: <input type="password" id="password"/><br />
        Email: <input type="text" id="email"/> <br />
        Serial: <input type="text" id="serial"/><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

When I submit it, it errors saying it cannot find the indices for username, password,email and serial. When I print_r the $_POST variable it only shows:

```
Array ( )
```

So nothing is being sent, but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jerzy said your fields doesn't contain name attributes, it should be like this:

```
<form action="do_register.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/> <br />
    Serial: <input type="text" name="serial" id="serial"/><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Just realized as soon as you posted.. /facepalm rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

your fields don't have `name` attributes. put the same what you now have in `id`

Comment: LOL! I didn't notice, thinking the answer was harder than that.